# Not able to print a string using scanner

Tags: java

Here the input for string is " hi how are you" but I am getting output as "hi" alone. Do let me know where is the error. I have tried out with nextLine() also.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Stringintalter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the num");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the Double");
        double b = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        String c = sc.next();  //tried out with nextLine() also.

        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

}
```

This is basic error only. I browsed a lot still I am not able to sort out the error.

Comment: try sc.next() + sc.nextLine(), this will work

Comment: add `sc.nextLine()` after `int a=...` and `double b ...`

Comment: @SeekAddo Yeah it is working . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @saimanoj you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

everytime you do

```
    int a = sc.nextInt();

    double b = sc.nextDouble();
```

your scanner is not reading the **newLine** token, so you should do something like:

```
     System.out.println("enter the num");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the Double");
    double b = sc.nextDouble();
    sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    String c = sc.next();  //tried out with nextLine() also.
```

Answer (score 1):

This code worked out for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Stringintalter {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("enter the num");
         int a = sc.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Enter the Double");
         double b = sc.nextDouble();
         System.out.println("Enter the string");
         sc.nextLine();
         String c = sc.nextLine();
         System.out.println(c);
         System.out.println(b);
         System.out.println(a);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help you.

```
Scanner u = new Scanner(System.in);

     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the num");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the Double");
    double b = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(a);


    String c;
    c = u.nextLine();
    System.out.println(c);
```